# ¿Porqué mi código tarda mas en ejecutarse de manera paralela?

Tags: c#, .net, bucle-for, hilos, programacion-asincrona

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop

Buenas, tengo este código que hice para multiplicar dos matrices  basándome en el ejemplo de la página que compartí arriba. Tengo un problema y es que la ejecución en paralelo tarda más que la ejecución de manera secuencial. Soy nuevo tanto en c# como en programación paralela, así que me cuesta entender porque pasa esto.

(Agregué un Console.WriteLine en la ejecución paralela para asegurarme de que se divida en distintos hilos la ejecución)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practica
{
    class Matriz
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int cantColumnasA = 2000, cantFilasB = 2000;   //estas dos cantidades tienen que coincidir
            int cantFilasA = 2000;
            int cantColumnasB = 2000;
            //con estas lineas definimos el tamaño de las matrices a tratar, se pueden variar para probar el rendimiento del programa

            double [, ] mA = inicializarMatriz(cantFilasA, cantColumnasA);
            double [, ] mB = inicializarMatriz(cantFilasB, cantColumnasB);

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            //ejecutar multiplicacion secuencial 
            Double [,] resultS = muliplicarMatrizSecuencial(mA, mB);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            var tiempoSecuencial =  stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000;

            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();
            //ejecutar multiplicacion paralelo
            Double [,] resultP = muliplicarMatrizParalelo(mA, mB);
            
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Tiempo for secuencial (segundos): {0}", tiempoSecuencial);
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Tiempo for Paralelo (segundos): {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000);

        }
        static double [,] muliplicarMatrizParalelo(double [, ] mA, double[, ] mB)
        {

            int filasA = mA.GetLength(0);
            int columnasA = mA.GetLength(1);
            int filasB = mB.GetLength(0);
            int columnasB = mB.GetLength(1);

            double temp;
            double[, ] resultado = new double[ filasA, columnasB];
            Parallel.For(0, filasA, i=>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    for(int j = 0; j < columnasB; j++)
                    {
                        temp = 0;
                        for(int z=0; z < columnasA ; z++)
                        {
                            temp += (mA[i, z] * mB[z, j]);
                        }
                        resultado[i,j] = temp;
                    }
                });
            return resultado;
        }

        static double [,] muliplicarMatrizSecuencial(double [, ] mA, double[, ] mB)
        {

            int filasA = mA.GetLength(0);
            int columnasA = mA.GetLength(1);
            int filasB = mB.GetLength(0);
            int columnasB = mB.GetLength(1);


            double[, ] resultado = new double[ filasA, columnasB];
            //Console.WriteLine("Filas result: "+resultado.GetLength(0).ToString()+", Columnas result: "+ resultado.GetLength(1).ToString());


            double temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < filasA; i++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                for(int j = 0; j < columnasB; j++)
                {
                    temp = 0;
                    for(int z=0; z < columnasA ; z++)
                    {
                        temp += (mA[i, z] * mB[z, j]);
                    }
                    resultado[i,j] = temp;
                }
            }
            return resultado;
        }


        static double[,] inicializarMatriz(int cantFilas, int cantColumnas)
        {
            double [,] matriz = new double[cantFilas, cantColumnas];
            Random al = new Random();

            for(int i=0; i<cantFilas; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j<cantColumnas; j++)
                {
                    matriz[i, j] = al.Next();
                }
            }
            return matriz;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Pues se me ocurre pensar que la línea `Console.WriteLine("thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)`, es la que consume un tiempo adicional en  la ejecución en paralelo, que no se consume en la ejecución de manera secuencial ya que en este último procedimiento, esta línea está comentada.

Comment: Lo cierto es que probé tu código, comentando la linea `//Console.WriteLine("thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)`, el tiempo de ejecución disminuye, pero sigue siendo mayor en la ejecución en paralelo, que en la ejecución de manera secuencial.

Comment: Si buscas hacer cálculos con matrices lo más rápido posible, sugiero que leas esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912766

Answer (score 0):

El problema yo creo que es porque es un "mal" ejemplo. Es bueno porque te enseña a usar el Parallel.For pero malo en el sentido de que no es un buen uso del paralelismo.

Lo que hay dentro del Parallel.For se ejecuta tan rápido que el código paralelo está todo el tiempo obteniendo y liberando threads. El paralelismo añade un tiempo para el manejo de los nuevos threads creados por eso se debe usar cuando la tarea consume mucho tiempo o cuando hay que esperar por algo.

El problema está en que el Parallel.For tiene 2000 tareas que ejecutar asi que empieza a crear threads a montones. Si bajas el número de filas en cantFilasA y aumentas las columnas, empieza a compensar. Aún así es dificil verlo. Con cantFilasA = 20 y cantColumnasA = 2000000 empieza a ser más rápido el paralelo.

Es más fácil de ver si pones algo tan tonto como un Thread.Sleep(50) dentro del primer for en ambos casos, las diferencias ya son muy visibles a favor del código paralelo desde el principio.
Ej:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int cantColumnasA = 200, cantFilasB = 200;   //estas dos cantidades tienen que coincidir
    int cantFilasA = 200;
    int cantColumnasB = 200;
    //con estas lineas definimos el tamaño de las matrices a tratar, se pueden variar para probar el rendimiento del programa

    double[,] mA = inicializarMatriz(cantFilasA, cantColumnasA);
    double[,] mB = inicializarMatriz(cantFilasB, cantColumnasB);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    //ejecutar multiplicacion secuencial 
    Double[,] resultS = muliplicarMatrizSecuencial(mA,mB);
    stopwatch.Stop();            

    Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch2.Start();
    //ejecutar multiplicacion paralelo
    Double[,] resultP = muliplicarMatrizParalelo(mA, mB);

    stopwatch2.Stop();
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Tiempo for secuencial (segundos): {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Tiempo for Paralelo (segundos): {0}", stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);

}
static double[,] muliplicarMatrizParalelo(double[,] mA, double[,] mB)
{

    int filasA = mA.GetLength(0);
    int columnasA = mA.GetLength(1);
    int filasB = mB.GetLength(0);
    int columnasB = mB.GetLength(1);

    double temp;
    double[,] resultado = new double[filasA, columnasB];
    Parallel.For(0, filasA, i =>
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine("thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        for (int j = 0; j < columnasB; j++)
        {
            temp = 0;
            for (int z = 0; z < columnasA; z++)
            {
                temp += (mA[i, z] * mB[z, j]);
            }
            resultado[i, j] = temp;
        }
    });
    return resultado;
}

static double[,] muliplicarMatrizSecuencial(double[,] mA, double[,] mB)
{

    int filasA = mA.GetLength(0);
    int columnasA = mA.GetLength(1);
    int filasB = mB.GetLength(0);
    int columnasB = mB.GetLength(1);


    double[,] resultado = new double[filasA, columnasB];
    //Console.WriteLine("Filas result: "+resultado.GetLength(0).ToString()+", Columnas result: "+ resultado.GetLength(1).ToString());


    double temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < filasA; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        //Console.WriteLine("thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        for (int j = 0; j < columnasB; j++)
        {
            temp = 0;
            for (int z = 0; z < columnasA; z++)
            {
                temp += (mA[i, z] * mB[z, j]);
            }
            resultado[i, j] = temp;
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}


static double[,] inicializarMatriz(int cantFilas, int cantColumnas)
{
    double[,] matriz = new double[cantFilas, cantColumnas];
    Random al = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < cantFilas; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cantColumnas; j++)
        {
            matriz[i, j] = al.Next();
        }
    }
    return matriz;
}
```

Comment: `Parallel` forma parte de TPL, lo que significa que funciona con `Task` y con hilos que obtiene de un `ThreadPool` por lo que no se la pasa creando hilos nuevos. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

Comment: Cierto. Fue por simplificar y simplifiqué demasiado. Pero si que se pasa obteniendo threads del pool, copiando la matriz que se pasa por parámetro, etc. Y luego con el semáforo esperando la respuesta del thread, etc. Es decir, un overhead de tiempo si que hay. Por eso no siempre paralelo significa más rápido.